# Array index returns undefined after push - Papa Parse

Tags: javascript, json, csv, parsing, papaparse

I used Papa Parse to parse a .csv file, and pushed the result to an empty array called `parsed_data`. I am able to use `console.log(parsed_data)`, and view the arrays produced. However, when I try to index the data, for example, `console.log(parsed_data[0])`, the result is undefined. Not sure what's going wrong here.

Example code:

```
    let parsed_data = [];
    const data_url = "acdata.csv";
    async function getData() {
        const response = await fetch(data_url);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const data = Papa.parse(blob, {
            complete: function(results) {
                //console.log("Finished:", results.data);   
                parsed_data.push(results.data); 
            }
        });

    };
    console.log(parsed_data);
    getData();
```

Comment: the `complete` callback is called asynchronously - the reason why you can see the result in the *console* is because arrays in the console are evaluated when you view them

Comment: you are mixing both sync and async code here

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for your reply. I've only just started using Javascript about a week ago. Could you elaborate a bit on what I need to do to be able to index the parsed_data array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Papa parse `complete` callback is called asynchronously, you'll need to wait for that to complete - however, papa parse doesn't seem to use Promises, so, you can "promisify" the parse function like so

```
const papaParsePromise = blob => new Promise(resolve => Papa.parse(blob, { complete: resolve }));
```

Another way of looking at that function, if you don't understand the `=>` notation, is

```
function papaParsePromise(blob) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        Papa.parse(blob, { 
            complete: function(data) {
                resolve(data);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

that returns a promise that resolves to the data that is passed to the complete callback

Your code would also need to wait for the promise returned by `getData` before it can use anything in that data. Unless your code is inside another `async` function, you'll need to use promise `.then` method, as below

```
const data_url = "acdata.csv";
async function getData() {
    // create a function that returns a Promise that resolves when papa parse complete is called
    const papaParsePromise = blob => new Promise(resolve => Papa.parse(blob, { complete: resolve }));
    const response = await fetch(data_url);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const data = await papaParsePromise(blob);
    return data;
};
getData()
.then(parse_data => {
    console.log(parsed_data);
    console.log(parsed_data[0]);
    // i.e. do what you need with parsed_data here
});
```

if, however, you are calling `getData` inside an `async` function - along with the changes to `getData` above, you can simply use `await getData()` to wait for the value - i.e.

```
async function someFunction() {
    const parsed_data = await getData();
    // do what you need with parsed_data here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works very well. I'll have to get familiar with async and arrow notation.